# Does OBD II pin 16 output is always 12 Volt?

Tags: obd-ii

Does OBD II pin 16 output is always 12 Volt?

Is it possible to the voltage is altering when ignition on, like rising from 12 to 14 Volt?

Or Voltage output of the buses, trailers, heavy duty vehicles OBD pin 16 is different than cars?

Comment: Yes, the OBD II port is always hot (12V). With wire strippers, electrical tape and a soldering iron you can modify anything that you want. The diagnostic connector on vehicles over 10,000lbs is not required by law to be OBD II.

Comment: Question I have reason to be misunderstood because it is short. To make it clear I changed the sentence.

Comment: The voltage in the OBD II connector is charging voltage. It is 12-12.6 ish volt engine off. It is 13.9-14.4 ish engine running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pin is the "battery voltage" of the vehicle.

Cars have a nominally 12V electrical system but the actual voltage can vary significantly. With the engine running it will be about 14V, with the engine off and the battery fully charged it will be about 12V. During starting or with a low battery it may drop significantly below 12V.

Large vehicles often have a nominally 24V electrical system. Again the actual voltage will vary significantly.

The connectors are keyed to prevent plugging a 12V diagnostic tool into a 24V vehicle.

Comment: It may be useful to add the link from the wikipedia page. Because it shows the pins and their meanings. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#OBD-II_diagnostic_connector